# Automatically start file download WITH/AFTER PHP form submit [SOLVED]

Tags: php, html, jquery, forms, download

So, after reviewing a lot of questions and answers that were mostly not working or far too complicated for no reason, and doing some testing, I now have a very easy and clean solution to automatically start a file download right before the PHP form gets processed, on the single click of the input button. I would like to share it with whoever is struggling to make this work quickly and simply.

Posting only relevant code blurbs, but this is a complete working solution for a "Get this e-brochure now" type of form to prevent download without filling the form.

### HTML

```
<form method="POST" onsubmit="downloadFilePDF()">
                <!-- your form here -->
                <input id="submit-download" type="submit" name="submit" disabled></input>
                <!-- optional recaptcha div -->
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="recaptcha_callback" data-expired-callback="recaptcha_expired_callback" data-sitekey="xxx"></div>
</form>
```

So we use the `POST` method, leave out the action attribute to stay on the same page and then specify the file path and name+extension in the `onsubmit` attribute. What is nice is that this attribute gets executed only when the form is submitted, including only when all fields (with the required attributes) are filled, which is what we want. I also use the attribute disabled in order to control the `reCATPCHA` completion (see JS code below for that).

### PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { //when submit button is clicked
    //recaptcha verification code here //
        if ($resp->isSuccess()) {
    // do what you want your form to do, probably store info from the input fields and/or mail() something
           
echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Thank you, you are now subscribed. Your download will start automatically.");</script>';} // pop up window that confirms all went well
    
else {echo '<script language="javascript">alert("A problem occurred with the robot verification.");</script>';}} // in other words, you are a bot
```

### CSS

to style the button when it is disabled to signal to the user they need to fill in the `reCAPTCHA` first hopefully they have seen such a situation before...

```
#submit-download[disabled],
#submit-download[disabled]:hover,
#submit-download[disabled]:active,
#submit-download[disabled]:focus { 
        background: #CCCCCC;
        box-shadow: none;
        outline: none;
        opacity: 0.5;
        text-decoration: none;
```

### JS/jQuery

Here we simply use the 2 callback functions that come with reCAPTCHA v2 from Google to specify what to do when 1) the reCAPTCHA is not filled and successed (first callback) and 2) what to do when the reCAPTCHA validation was done but has expired (second callback)

- [UPDATE] we obfuscate the code using obfuscator.io to discourage direct download. Original code for function downloadFilePDF() was :

```
 window.open('/assets/The_Foolproof_Guide_to_Making_Your_Website_Multilingual.pdf')
```

other JS code

```
    function recaptcha_callback() {
       $('#submit-download').removeAttr('disabled');
        }; 
        
     function recaptcha_expired_callback() {
       $('#submit-download').prop('disabled', true);
        };
```

```
 downloadFilePDF() {obfuscated_code_here};
```

}

```
## .htaccess ##

Add these lines to force Save As for your filetype otherwise it will probably open in a new window directly in the browser (which I didn't want.)



    <FilesMatch "\.(?i:pdf)$">
      ForceType application/octet-stream
      Header set Content-Disposition attachment
    </FilesMatch>



So, using this code alltogether, what will happen in the user flow is:

1) Form with submit button greyed out.
2) Completes the fields marked as required and/or completes the reCATPCHA validation (whichever order first).
3) Submit button becomes colored and enabled again ('disabled' attribut is removed by the JS function from the captcha callback).
4. Click on submit button calls first "onsubmit=", forces the download as "Save as" (because of the specifications we added to .htaccess), THEN will process whatever code you have in the second if condition.

Et voilà.

A live example can be seen here => [http://oxoinnovation.com/multilingual-translation-guide-temp][1]


  [1]: https://oxoinnovation.com/multilingual-translation-guide-temp

## UPDATE ##

To prevent the link from being downloaded when checking source code, I have obfuscated it using obfuscator.io –
```

Comment: Normally to post your own solution, you would add this as an answer to one of the questions you researched with the reasons why they should use your answer (just as you've posted here).  Alternatively you would post a question with the relevant details and post an answer (which is what you have included in your question).  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question may give some pointers.

Comment: _“this is a complete working solution for a "Get this e-brochure now" type of form to prevent download without filling the form.”_ - is it though? Currently don’t see what’s stopping me from putting a direct link to `http://your-domain.xy/path/to/file.pdf` anywhere on the web, to have people download it immedaitely with one single click …

Comment: @NigelRen thank you for that, I'm very new to SO so I will take this advice for the future.

Comment: @CBroe that's a good point, more technical-aware people can do that; I will work on a better solution. Thanks

Comment: @CBroe so first of all thanks for pointing this out. Secondly, I have replaced the onsubmit event with a JS function that i have obfuscated a lot so to discourage people to access the link directly. It's not perfect but should discourage a lot of people.

Comment: I used this tool https://obfuscator.io/